# how to convert a text file into a json object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

i have a text file that it's structure is like a json object, when i read from file with fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString() command, it converts it to string, then how can i use it as a json object?

Comment: I believe you should be able to just use `JSON.parse(json)` if it's valid json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse it with `JSON.parse`

`JSON.parse(myString)`

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse('json string here')`.

```
JSON.parse('{ "a": "123" }');
```

if the content of text is not valid json, like `{ a: 123 }`,

```
function parse(text) {
  return Function(`return ${ text }`)();
}
parse('{ a: 123 }');
```